# Ajax load content by class (or li)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write an ajax slider of sorts.  Of course being new to this I find myself lost in the sea of unhelpful google-ing.  What's supposed to happen is that when you click next (or previous) I want to load in the next (or previous) list item and remove the original item from the DOM.  As my code stands now I can get the "starting" list item to show up but then nothing happens when I click next (or previous).  Also the way I have it set up now is that it loads all the content in the containing div at the same time instead of fetching the specific list item which I don't/haven't figured out how to do which is where you come in.

Important Main Page HTML

```
<div id="navButtons">
    <div style="float:left" id="prevBtn">PREV</div>
    <div style="float:right" id="nextBtn">NEXT</div>
</div>

<div id="contentBox" style="clear:both;margin:0 auto">

</div>
```

External HTML (to be loaded via ajax)

```
<div id="contentBox" style="clear:both;margin:0 auto">
     <ul>
        <li class="loadContent">CONTENT 1</li>
        <li class="loadContent">CONTENT 2</li>
        <li class="loadContent">CONTENT 3</li>        
        <li id="start" class="loadContent">CONTENT 4</li>        
        <li class="loadContent">CONTENT 5</li>        
        <li class="loadContent">CONTENT 6</li>        
        <li class="loadContent">CONTENT 7</li>        
        <li class="loadContent">CONTENT 8</li>
        <li class="loadContent">CONTENT 9</li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#prevBtn, #nextBtn{cursor:pointer}
.loadContent { width:100px; height:40px; ;
        float:left; border:2px blue solid; 
        padding:2px;display:none }
  ul, li{list-style-type:none}
  #start{display:block}
```

jQuery (which I placed right after #contentBox)

```
var $curr = $("#start");
    $("#contentBox").load("testContent.aspx #contentBox");
        $("#prevBtn").click(function () {
            $curr = $curr.prev('li');
            $('li').css("display", "none");
            $curr.css("display", "block");
        });
        $('#nextBtn').click(function () {
            $curr = $curr.next('li');
            $('li').css("display", "none");
            $curr.css("display", "block");
        });
```

[JSFiddle if it's helpful...](http://jsfiddle.net/comatoseduck/bjVnr/)

**Bonus Question**: How can I get the old content to slide left off the screen and the new content to slide left onto the "stage"?

Comment: If all of your list items are on one page (testContent.aspx) it doesn't make sense to request them one by one, as that means the server has to build and send that page for each list item and the browser has to receive that page for each list item. Very inefficient. I would suggest taking a look at malsup's cycle plugin. It can handle both your original question and the bonus question, along with next and previous buttons.

Comment: Malsup's doesn't handle ajax by default, that would have to be custom code.

Comment: First off you set $curr to en element that doesn't even exist since you haven't loaded it yet `var $curr = $("#start");`. By the way, if you move this one line to after you load your data, it will allow the prev/next to work.

Comment: Balls @KevinB you're right I was afraid that the way I was approaching this might be inefficient.  What if I were to load a separate .aspx file on each next/prev click?  I tried playing with it to no avail.

Comment: It would be efficient if your aspx file only returned the one list item that it needed rather than the entire list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery to this:

```
$("#contentBox").load("testContent.aspx #contentBox", function(){
    var $curr = $("#start");
    $("#prevBtn").click(function () {
        $curr = $curr.prev('li');
        $('li').css("display", "none");
        $curr.css("display", "block");
    });
    $('#nextBtn').click(function () {
        $curr = $curr.next('li');
        $('li').css("display", "none");
        $curr.css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

You're setting the $curr variable to an element that only gets returned from your .load() call so it doesn't exist when you set it. By placing it in the callback of the .load() function, it will be assigned once the data comes across.